# Creating a header for Gsoap without WSDL

Tags: c++, wsdl, gsoap

I want to make my own header file for Gsoap as I do not have any wsdl (or a website to generate a header file from). What are the things I need to mention in my header file?

I followed the steps mentioned in https://www.genivia.com/dev.html but I keep getting errors as `soap_serve(soap_new()) function is not defined in stdsoap2.cpp`. Also, I am not sure if I need to mention all the comments like:

```
// gsoap ns service name: ...

// gsoap ns service namespace: ...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

This is what I have done so far before getting stuck:

- From the aforementioned website, I downloaded Gsoap and changed the environment variables to run wsdl2h and soapcpp2. I then tried one of their examples (hello.h, hello.cpp)
- I made the header file as mentioned on the link and ran "soapcpp2 hello.h" again, as mentioned (using the developer environment of VS2017).
- I then made hello.cpp as per the link and used their statement `c++ -o hello.cgi hello.cpp soapC.cpp soapServer.cpp stdsoap2.cpp` but replaced c++ with cl and -o with /Fe.
- Since stdsoap2.cpp was not generated, I copied that file along with its header and pasted it in my current directory.
- Now the new error mentions that `soap_serve(soap_new()) is not defined` which, once I looked at stdsoap2 files, was not.

Have no idea what could cause the problem and how to get this to run properly as I am new to Gsoap and WSDL.

Hope this description is helpful!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: @kiner_shah Wonder if its something to do with the hello.cpp file or the header file..

Comment: Is `soapH.h` included in your code? It seems the functions `soap_serve()` and `soap_new()` are declared and defined in that header file.

Comment: I found out that `soap_new()` was added in gSOAP 2.X. Please check which version of gSOAP you are using! See [link](https://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc5)

Answer (score 0):

No WSDL? Maybe gSoap is not a good choice then.

Would you mind to try [webcc](https://github.com/sprinfall/webcc)? It's a lightweight C++ REST and SOAP client and server library based on Boost.Asio. In the `example` folder, you can find great examples.

Comment: I found out that it is almost impossible to work without a WSDL. I got some stuff working by setting up my own server using iis and using its address to get results!